# Putty, SSH "Access denied"

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a problem with SSH, i'm using putty, on the windows machine.

I have a virtual machine(VirtualBox) on another windows machine with ubuntu 17.10.

I can ping from one machine to the other and the IPs are different on the 
virtual machine I set up a Bridge connection.

I opened ports 22 from the firewall of both machines.

Putty connects with a message "login as:@192.168.0.148's password:"

When I enter the password, it gives me this message "Access denied"

I tried to change the putty settings like... SSH-->Auth-->GSSAPI--->Attempt GSSAPI authetication (SSH-2 only)remove the check.

I tried to edit the ubuntu file "sshd_config" #PermitRootLogin yes

I attach the SSDSconfig file and putty logs

fileSSDH:

```
#$OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

FileLogPutty:

```
2018-03-02 09:27:55 Connecting to 192.168.0.148 port 22
2018-03-02 09:27:55 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.70
2018-03-02 09:27:55 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1
2018-03-02 09:27:55 Using SSH protocol version 2
2018-03-02 09:27:55 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
2018-03-02 09:27:55 Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
2018-03-02 09:27:55 Host key fingerprint is:
2018-03-02 09:27:55 ssh-ed25519 256 fd:39:ae:b6:69:fb:f6:bd:e3:5f:78:fb:90:e5:2c:b0
2018-03-02 09:27:55 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
2018-03-02 09:27:55 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
2018-03-02 09:27:55 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
2018-03-02 09:27:55 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
2018-03-02 09:28:04 Sent password
2018-03-02 09:28:06 Password authentication failed
2018-03-02 09:28:11 Sent password
2018-03-02 09:28:13 Password authentication failed
```

Comment: `login as:@192.168.0.148's password:` is missing the username I think? do you set it? The format is `<user>@<host|ip>`. Maybe this should be `root@192.168.0.148`?

Comment: can you ssh to the machine, when you are on it - i.e. to itself?

Comment: @urban 
maybe yes, where can I set it?

Comment: @developer 
I do not know now I try

Comment: If I remember right, on putty in the server address field just prepend `<user>@`... Seems like there is also auto-login option but I have never tried it: https://www.electrictoolbox.com/specifying-auto-login-name-putty/

Comment: @urban 
oh my god thank you so much it works !!!!

Comment: Please don't add texts like "Solved" to the title. Instead, mark the most helpful answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark below the downvote button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Comments:

> If I remember right, on putty in the server address field just prepend @... Seems like there is also auto-login option but I have never tried it: [electrictoolbox.com/specifying-auto-login-name-putty](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/specifying-auto-login-name-putty/)

- [urban](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3727050/urban)

Response by the Asker:

> Oh my god thank you so much it works!
>   - [Riky Proti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8252860/riky-proti)

I'm answering this so other users with the same problem can easily determine the answer that was provided.